# What happens to $\frac{|x-3|}{x}<2$ for $x\geq 3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, absolute-value

I need to find real numbers $x$ that satisfy the inequality
$\frac{|x-3|}{x}<2$

My analysis goes like this:

Case 1) $x<0$

Then, $\frac{|x-3|}{x}<0<2$, so all negative $x$ satisfy the inequality.

Case 2) $0<x<3$

Then, $\frac{3-x}{x}<2$, and as $x>0$, we can say $3-x<2x\implies x>1$

$\therefore x\in(1,3)$ satisfies the inequality, but $x\in(0,1]$ does not.

This is all fine, but my issue is in the 3rd case.

Case 3) $x\geq 3$

Then, $\frac{x-3}{x}<2$

$\iff x-3<2x$

$\iff x>-3$

What does the final line tell us about the $x\geq 3$ case?

When I plot $\frac{|x-3|}{x}$, I can see that all $x\geq 3$ satisfy the inequality, but why does the $x>-3$ result tell us this?

Comment: It doesn't. You must take the intersection of both interval.

Comment: The final line tells you that the inequality holds for every $x\geq 3$. (which makes sense as you have a fraction with larger denominator, $x-3<x$).

Comment: Clarification: formally you get "for all $x\geq 3$ if in addition $x>3$ then the inequality holds" and clearly, the "addition" doesn't matter.

Comment: @ChristianF I see what you mean. The intersection of $x\geq 3$ and $x>-3$ is simply $x \geq 3$. Indeed, I've applied this same logic in case 2. So in conclusion, the solution set is $\{x\in \Re : (x<0)\cup  (x>1)\}$.

Comment: @HumptyDumpty True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic might be more clear if you reverse the steps in the $x\ge3$ case, keeping only the reverse direction of the if-and-only-if double arrow:

$$x\ge3\implies x\gt-3\implies x-3\lt2x\implies{x-3\over x}\lt2\implies{|x-3|\over x}\lt2$$

where the first $\implies$ is trivial, the second is easy, and the final two depend on the assumption $x\ge3$ (which implies $x\gt0$ and $x-3=|x-3|$ for those two steps, respectively).

Answer (score 1):

Any way, you don't have to consider 3 cases. If $x>0$ you get $$|x-3|<2x$$ so $$-2x<x-3<2x$$...

Answer (score 0):

You get two cases: At first:$$x>0$$ and $$x\geq 3$$ so we get $$x-3<2x$$
Case two: $$x<0$$ and $$x<3$$ so we get $$-(x-3)>2x$$
And we get $$x<0$$ or $$x>1$$